# Two background sprites causes performance problems

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm building a cocos2d game where I use two background sprites, actually one is a sprite, the other one is a CCMask that is used to make holes into the other background, but the performance problem is the same even when using 2 regular background sprites on top of each other.

When I use one background sprite, my FPS is around 60 all the time, when I use two background sprites the FPS drops to 30 every time. I've googled around, tried different solutions including reading sprites from a sprite frame cash instead of from a file, unfortunately the result is the same.

I just can't figure out why this is happening. Does any one here have any idea why this is happening and how to get around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On older devices (1st & 2nd generation, ie iPhone 3G) this can easily happen since they have terrible fillrates.

If possible try to SpriteBatch the two background images. You need to add both to a texture atlas, for example with TexturePacker. Sprite batching is particularly effective if the sprites are large.

Also, just in case: don't test performance in the Simulator. Simulator performance has no relation to actual device performance whatsoever.

Comment: I've tried SpriteBatch with the same effect. However, I haven't yet tried it on an actual device, only in the simulator mode. I will perform some tests on the device later today, I really hope that you are right about performance being different on the device than that from the simulator.

Comment: You were right LearnCocos2D :) The performance was not an issue on the actual device. I think I spent almost 2 days looking for a solution to a problem that didn't exist.. Anyway, thanks for pointing me in the right direction! :)